# Can you solve this recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations, recursion

The function $M(n,s)$ represents the number of ways to distribute n indistinguishable objects into s different containers/sets. It adheres to the following recurrence relation:

$M(n,s+1) = \sum^{n}_{k = 0} M(k,s)$

If anyone could find a closed form expression of $M(n,z)$ or tell me why it's not possible to find it i would greatly appreciate it.

Note: $M(1,s) = s$ and $M(n,1) = 1$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try generating functions (two-variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its actually a question about Combinatorics, the number of ways to distribute n indistinguishable objects into s different containers/sets equals to ${n+s-1 \choose n}$.
in the equation you wrote, its can be represent as recursive call cause the sigma is for all the ways to put the rest of the objects (the $n-k$) in the $(s+1)$'s container/set, and to distribute the $k$ into the other $s$ baskets.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you elaborate a bit on how you arrived at the solution and why this ends up being a binomial coefficient?

Comment: the first is just the definition in textbooks for this problem, the formal solution is to think of the objects lined in a row and put between them $s-1$ partitions, which will create the $s$'s containers. so its equal to find $s-1$ spots for those partitions in the line, which in size of $n+s-1$.
which equal to ${n+s-1 \choose n}$